# Select Statement inside a procedure in Oracle

Tags: select, stored-procedures, oracle10g

sorry for asking this question but it's because none of the answers given before are enough for me to understand. I want to write a stored procedure that returns all the columns in a table.As an ad hod query I just write

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
```

but here, I get an error which prompts me to provide `INTO` clause which I don't understand why and how.Could someone explain how would I do that both in the above case and when I want to return just one column values(multiple rows).

Comment: please show the code you tried, the exact errors you're getting, and read the pl/sql documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

People with a SQL Server background are used to writing stored procedures that return whole query results and so try to write PL/SQL procedures something like this:

```
procedure get_emps is
begin
    -- this will NOT work!
    select * from emp;
end;
```

Unfortunately it's not that simple.  Probably the nearest equivalent in PL/SQL is a function returning a ref cursor:

```
function get_emps return sys_refcursor is
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for
        select * from emp;
    return rc;
end;
```

You could call this from a calling program like this:

```
declare
    cur sys_refcursor;
    emp_rec emp%rowtype;
begin
    cur := get_emps;
    loop
        fetch cur into emp_rec;
        exit when cur%notfound;
    end loop;
    close cur;
end;
```

or in SQL Plus you could do:

```
var rc refcursor
:rc := get_emps;
print rc
```

Comment: Dear, Tony, I'll both vote up and accept your answer if you could just tell me how it's done

Comment: How what is done? Sorry I took "Thank you Tony.I got it all" to mean you fully understood my answer.  What don't you understand?

Comment: I mean how do I vote up and accept your answer.I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Oh right!  Well, there is an "up arrow" triangle at the top left of my answer to vote up.  And I think there is a tick icon near there to accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you Tony. I accepted your answer.Could not vote up though as my reputation is below 15