# select statement not working in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create table Employee(Id number,
                  Name varchar(20),
                  Age number,
                  DId number,
                  Salary number,
         primary key(Id),
         foreign key(DId) references Department on delete cascade);

declare
  total number;
  procedure myFunction(x in number) is 
     begin
       insert into Employee values(17,'Jaskaran Singh',31,1,200000);
       dbms_output.put_line('successfully executed');
       select * from Employee;
      end;
   begin
     myFunction(3);
   end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You performed a `select` without returning it or using its data in any way.

Comment: i just want to print the data

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029802/select-statement-inside-a-procedure-in-oracle on how to use select inside procedure/functions

Comment: @mohitsahu So you should iterate over the results and `dbms_output` them.

Answer (score 0):

To return data from stored procedure, you should create a cursor and return that select like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TYPES
AS
   TYPE DATA_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
END;
```

then in your code is going to be like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROC(RESULTSET OUT TYPES.DATA_CURSOR)  AS
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(17,'Jaskaran Singh',31,1,200000);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('successfully executed');

    OPEN RESULTSET FOR
      SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
      END;
```

The Execution part like

```
DECLARE THE_RESULT_SET OUT TYPES.DATA_CURSOR;
   BEGIN
     MYPROC(3, THE_RESULT_SET);
    --     You can now get the THE_RESULT_SET and take the result from it...
   END;
```

**Important**: if you want to print as I understand the other case, you can get that result (same code), and loop whatever you want and print the result from the THE_RESULT_SET

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print what's in the EMPLOYEES table you have loop a cursor over the EMPLOYEES table, printing each row appropriately. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE
  TOTAL NUMBER;

  PROCEDURE MYFUNCTION(X IN NUMBER) IS 
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(17,'Jaskaran Singh',31,1,200000);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('successfully executed');

      FOR aRow IN (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID=' || aRow.ID ||
                             ' NAME=''' || aRow.NAME || '''' ||
                             ' AGE=' || aRow.AGE ||
                             ' DID=' || aRow.DID ||
                             ' SALARY=' || aRow.SALARY);
      END LOOP;
  END;
BEGIN
  MYFUNCTION(3);
END;
```

Share and enjoy.