# Oracle Procedure - PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm getting a following error with my procedure at execution:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
exec p_matrika(2010,2.5,'26311330')
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_MATRIKA'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Procedure compiles without errors. I also checked SQL statement and it works as it should, returning 1 row, so there must be I'm doing something wrong in procedure itself. I apologize for a little messed up formatting of SQL statement. It somehow messed up when I copied and pasted it.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_MATRIKA 
(
    leto IN NUMBER, 
    rating IN NUMBER,
    davcna IN VARCHAR2,
    unsec_out OUT NUMBER,
    supp_out OUT NUMBER,
    sec_out OUT NUMBER,
    unsec_limit OUT NUMBER,
    supp_limit OUT NUMBER,
    sec_limit OUT NUMBER,
    unsec_tenor OUT NUMBER,
    supp_tenor OUT NUMBER,
    sec_tenor OUT NUMBER
)
AS
    out_unsec NUMBER;
    out_supp NUMBER;
    out_sec NUMBER;
    limit_unsec NUMBER;
    limit_supp NUMBER;
    limit_sec NUMBER;
    tenor_unsec NUMBER;
    tenor_supp NUMBER;
    tenor_sec NUMBER;       
BEGIN
    with 
        matrika_osnova 
    as
    (
    select distinct a.par_davcna, nvl(a.unsecured,0) unsec_out,
                 nvl(a.supported,0) supp_out, nvl(a.secured,0) sec_out,
                 x.tip_sub, x.cispri, x.kraban, x.dolfinobv,
                 y.ltv_tip, y.rating, y.unsec_pct, q.supp_pct,
                 w.sec_pct, p.unsec_maxznes, s.sec_maxznes,
                 case when y.unsec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) > nvl(p.unsec_maxznes,0) then
                                     nvl(p.unsec_maxznes,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                            else
                                    case when y.unsec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - 
                                                        nvl(x.kraban,0) + (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5) < 0 then
                                                        0
                                            else
                                                        y.unsec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                                    end
                 end unsec_max,
                 case when q.supp_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) > nvl(s.sec_maxznes,0) then
                                     nvl(s.sec_maxznes,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                            else
                                    case when q.supp_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5) < 0 then
                                                        0
                                            else
                                                        q.supp_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                                    end
                 end supp_max,
                 case when w.sec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) > nvl(s.sec_maxznes,0) then
                                     nvl(s.sec_maxznes,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                            else
                                    case when w.sec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5) < 0 then
                                                        0
                                            else
                                                        w.sec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                                    end
                 end sec_max,
                 d.unsec_tenor, e.supp_tenor, f.sec_tenor                               
    from sco_matrika_banka a
    inner join
                        (select b.tip_sub, b.par_davcna, b.cispri, b.kraban, b.dolfinobv
                         from scoring_gvin b
                         where b.leto = leto) x --IN parameter
    on a.par_davcna = x.par_davcna
    inner join 
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                         a.max_znesek unsec_maxznes
                         from sco_sif_ltv_maxznes a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 1) p
    on x.tip_sub = p.tip_sub
    inner join 
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                         a.max_znesek sec_maxznes
                         from sco_sif_ltv_maxznes a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 3) s
    on x.tip_sub = s.tip_sub
    inner join
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                                        a.rating, a.ltv_pct unsec_pct
                         from sco_sif_ltv_pct a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 1
                         and a.rating = rating) y --IN parameter
    on x.tip_sub = y.tip_sub
    inner join
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                                        a.rating, a.ltv_pct supp_pct
                         from sco_sif_ltv_pct a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 2
                         and a.rating = rating) q --IN parameter
    on x.tip_sub = y.tip_sub
    inner join
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                                        a.rating, a.ltv_pct sec_pct
                         from sco_sif_ltv_pct a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 3
                         and a.rating = rating) w --IN parameter
    on x.tip_sub = y.tip_sub
    inner join
                         (select a.tip_sub, a.tenor unsec_tenor
                            from sco_sif_ltv_tenor a
                            where a.ltv_tip = 1) d
    on x.tip_sub = d.tip_sub
    inner join
                         (select a.tip_sub, a.tenor supp_tenor
                            from sco_sif_ltv_tenor a
                            where a.ltv_tip = 2) e
    on x.tip_sub = e.tip_sub
    inner join
                         (select a.tip_sub, a.tenor sec_tenor
                            from sco_sif_ltv_tenor a
                            where a.ltv_tip = 3) f
    on x.tip_sub = f.tip_sub
    where a.par_davcna = davcna) --IN parameter

    select a.unsec_out, a.supp_out, a.sec_out,
                 case when a.unsec_max - a.unsec_out < 0 then
                                     0
                            else
                                     a.unsec_max - a.unsec_out
                 end unsec_limit,
                             case when a.supp_max - a.supp_out < 0 then
                                     0
                            else
                                     a.supp_max - a.supp_out
                 end supp_limit,
                             case when a.sec_max - a.sec_out < 0 then
                                     0
                            else
                                     a.sec_max - a.sec_out
                 end sec_limit,
                 a.unsec_tenor, a.supp_tenor, a.sec_tenor
                 into
                 out_unsec, out_supp, out_sec, limit_unsec, limit_supp,
                 limit_sec, tenor_unsec, tenor_supp, tenor_sec
    from matrika_osnova a;

    unsec_out := out_unsec;
    supp_out := out_supp;
    sec_out := out_sec;
    unsec_limit := limit_unsec;
    supp_limit := limit_supp;
    sec_limit := limit_sec;
    unsec_tenor := tenor_unsec;
    supp_tenor := tenor_supp;
    sec_tenor := tenor_sec;             
END P_MATRIKA;
```

Comment: Your procedure has 12 parameters and you are only passing 3. Where do you expect the OUT values to go?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your swift reply. I'm pretty new to PL/SQL. My goal is to get a row with 9 OUT parameters specified.

Comment: Your procedure has multiple scalar out parameters, you won't get a 'row' at all. What do you plan to do with the results of the call; how will you use the values? And how many rows will the query in your procedure actually return - always exactly one? (Not sure why you are using a procedure here at all, instead of just running the query directly.)

Comment: It suppose to return values to my C# app. Yes, always exactly 1 row. I could use in-line SQL, but that way SQL has to compile every time I run it, whereas stored procedure is compiled only once.

Comment: That isn't correct. There is a hard-parse of the SQL if it isn't in the cache, and a quicker soft-parse if it is. The PL/SQL for the procedure is compiled once, the SQL it calls is treated the same as a direct call, and will still get a soft parse. You may still want it in a procedure for other reasons, like maintainability etc. though.

Comment: Ok, like I said I'm new. I just read that when using in-line SQL explain plan has to be made at every call, whereas with SP is made only once. Still, I don't know what's wrong with my procedure. This example at Oracle site looks similar. `CREATE PROCEDURE GET_SINGLE_CUSTOMERINFO
(
   P_ID IN INTEGER,
   P_AGE OUT INTEGER,
   P_OCCUPATION OUT VARCHAR2,
   P_LASTSTATEMENTBALANCE OUT FLOAT
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT AGE, OCCUPATION, LASTSTATEMENTBALANCE INTO P_AGE, P_OCCUPATION, 
          P_LASTSTATEMENTBALANCE 
   FROM CROSSSELLCUSTOMERS 
   WHERE CROSSSELLCUSTOMERS.ID = P_ID;
END;`

Comment: Your procedure isn't the problem, it's how you're calling it that's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the same number of arguments in your call as there are formal parameters in the procedure specifictation (unless there are any defaulted IN parameters, which isn't the case here). Each OUT parameter has to have a corresponding variable from the caller for the value to be put into. Your procedure has 12 formal parameters. At the moment you are providing values for the three IN parameters, but you aren't providing variables to accept the nine OUT parameters.

You can use local PL/SQL variables declared in the same anonymous block as your call or - probably more usefully and close to your C# call - bind variables, which in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer (based on your use of `exec`) you can define with the `variable` command:

```
variable out_unsec NUMBER;
variable out_supp NUMBER;
variable out_sec NUMBER;
variable limit_unsec NUMBER;
variable limit_supp NUMBER;
variable limit_sec NUMBER;
variable tenor_unsec NUMBER;
variable tenor_supp NUMBER;
variable tenor_sec NUMBER;     

exec p_matrika(2010, 2.5, '26311330', :out_unsec, :out_supp, :out_sec, -
  :limit_unsec, :limit_supp, :limit_sec, :tenor_unsec, :tenor_supp, :tenor_sec);

print out_unsec
print out_supp
...
```

You can use the bind variables in later code in a script, for instance, and they would be available in C# via your call from there.

That's a bit messy to set up for testing, though SQL Developer can semi-automate it. It also assumes that there will always be exactly one result, which you've said is the case, but if there are ever no results or more than one you will get an exception from the procedure.

(Incidentally, you don't need the local variables in your procedure; your query can select straight into `unsec_out`, you don't need a separate intermediate `out_unsec`. You might also want to think about a naming convention, e.g. `p_out_unsec` for the formal parameter, ans `l_out_unsec` for the local variable, if you decide to keep it. Makes it much easier to see what you're using and modifying, your current names are asy to confuse).

Another approach is to use a ref cursor instead:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_MATRIKA 
(
    leto IN NUMBER, 
    rating IN NUMBER,
    davcna IN VARCHAR2,
    p_refcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_refcur FOR
    ... your query
END;
```

You can then do:

```
var refcur refcursor
exec p_matrika(2010, 2.5, '26311330', :refcur);
print refcur
```

Or you could make it a function that returns a ref cursor. Your C# code can then treat the bound ref cursor like any other result set.

Comment: Alex, thank you for your detailed answer. It's obvious that you're very knowledgeable, probably too knowledgeable for me :-). I read and re-read your answer several times, tried to use your solutions and just can't get it work. Probably - due to my lack of knowledge - I'm not using your suggested implementations correctly. With all of your help I still can't get it work. I can't understand how procedure with 1 OUT parameter works as expected in my C# code, but it doesn't work when I include more then 1 OUT parameter. In C# I just use SP in CommandText, set in and out parameters and it works.

Comment: Does it work for you in SQL\*Plus/SQL Developer? In C# you need to set all 9 OUT parameters - with the right direction - and have the right number of bind placeholders in the command text for them all. If it does wotk in SQL\*Plus but you still can't get the call right in C#, it would be better to ask a new question showing the procedure specification and your best attempt at the C# code, plus the error you still get. (And set the right tags)

Comment: No, I can't managed to work in SQL Developer, neither in C#. Maybe my approach is wrong from the beginning. In essence, what I would need is a procedure or function that would return my SQL statement result to my C# app, that is: 1 row with 9 fields, as specified in OUT parameters. But Alex, nevertheless I would kindly like to thank you for all of your effort in order to help me. Really appreciated. Take care.

Comment: @Flin - if you want one row back then use the ref cursor approach. Either as a procedure put parameter, or a function return value.

Comment: [Here's a simple example with a function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6029963/266304)..

Comment: Alex, I managed to sort this out with ref cursor, as you suggested! I wouldn't be able to do this without your help, well at least not so quickly :-). It would probably take days for me to figure it out. Thanks again for all of your help. You're a star! I'll post my answer shortly. And, almost forgot, I up-voted your answer. It's just not visible (stored internally as message said), as I'm so new to StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve my problem. Or yet better said, Alex Poole solved it, so kudos to him :-).

Oracle Stored Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE P_MATRIKA 
(
    p_leto IN NUMBER, 
    p_rating IN NUMBER,
    p_davcna IN VARCHAR2,
    p_refcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_refcur FOR
    with 
        matrika_osnova 
    as
    (
    select distinct a.par_davcna, nvl(a.unsecured,0) unsec_out,
                 nvl(a.supported,0) supp_out, nvl(a.secured,0) sec_out,
                 x.tip_sub, x.cispri, x.kraban, x.dolfinobv,
                 y.ltv_tip, y.rating, y.unsec_pct, q.supp_pct,
                 w.sec_pct, p.unsec_maxznes, s.sec_maxznes,
                 case when y.unsec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) > nvl(p.unsec_maxznes,0) then
                                     nvl(p.unsec_maxznes,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                            else
                                    case when y.unsec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - 
                                                        nvl(x.kraban,0) + (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5) < 0 then
                                                        0
                                            else
                                                        y.unsec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                                    end
                 end unsec_max,
                 case when q.supp_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) > nvl(s.sec_maxznes,0) then
                                     nvl(s.sec_maxznes,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                            else
                                    case when q.supp_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5) < 0 then
                                                        0
                                            else
                                                        q.supp_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                                    end
                 end supp_max,
                 case when w.sec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) > nvl(s.sec_maxznes,0) then
                                     nvl(s.sec_maxznes,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                            else
                                    case when w.sec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5) < 0 then
                                                        0
                                            else
                                                        w.sec_pct * nvl(x.cispri,0) - nvl(x.kraban,0) + 
                                                        (nvl(x.dolfinobv,0)/5)
                                    end
                 end sec_max,
                 d.unsec_tenor, e.supp_tenor, f.sec_tenor                               
    from sco_matrika_banka a
    inner join
                        (select b.tip_sub, b.par_davcna, b.cispri, b.kraban, b.dolfinobv
                         from scoring_gvin b
                         where b.leto = p_leto) x --IN parameter
    on a.par_davcna = x.par_davcna
    inner join 
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                         a.max_znesek unsec_maxznes
                         from sco_sif_ltv_maxznes a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 1) p
    on x.tip_sub = p.tip_sub
    inner join 
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                         a.max_znesek sec_maxznes
                         from sco_sif_ltv_maxznes a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 3) s
    on x.tip_sub = s.tip_sub
    inner join
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                                        a.rating, a.ltv_pct unsec_pct
                         from sco_sif_ltv_pct a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 1
                         and a.rating = p_rating) y --IN parameter
    on x.tip_sub = y.tip_sub
    inner join
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                                        a.rating, a.ltv_pct supp_pct
                         from sco_sif_ltv_pct a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 2
                         and a.rating = p_rating) q --IN parameter
    on x.tip_sub = y.tip_sub
    inner join
                        (select a.tip_sub, a.ltv_tip, 
                                        a.rating, a.ltv_pct sec_pct
                         from sco_sif_ltv_pct a
                         where a.ltv_tip = 3
                         and a.rating = p_rating) w --IN parameter
    on x.tip_sub = y.tip_sub
    inner join
                         (select a.tip_sub, a.tenor unsec_tenor
                            from sco_sif_ltv_tenor a
                            where a.ltv_tip = 1) d
    on x.tip_sub = d.tip_sub
    inner join
                         (select a.tip_sub, a.tenor supp_tenor
                            from sco_sif_ltv_tenor a
                            where a.ltv_tip = 2) e
    on x.tip_sub = e.tip_sub
    inner join
                         (select a.tip_sub, a.tenor sec_tenor
                            from sco_sif_ltv_tenor a
                            where a.ltv_tip = 3) f
    on x.tip_sub = f.tip_sub
    where a.par_davcna = p_davcna) --IN parameter

    select a.unsec_out, a.supp_out, a.sec_out,
                 case when a.unsec_max - a.unsec_out < 0 then
                                     0
                            else
                                     a.unsec_max - a.unsec_out
                 end unsec_limit,
                             case when a.supp_max - a.supp_out < 0 then
                                     0
                            else
                                     a.supp_max - a.supp_out
                 end supp_limit,
                             case when a.sec_max - a.sec_out < 0 then
                                     0
                            else
                                     a.sec_max - a.sec_out
                 end sec_limit,
                 a.unsec_tenor, a.supp_tenor, a.sec_tenor
    from matrika_osnova a;
END;
```

C# Code:

```
public void LoadMatrika(string davcna)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = CreateConnection())
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "P_MATRIKA";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_leto", Util.letoc));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_rating", Score.Rating));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_davcna", davcna));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_refcur", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));
            cmd.BindByName = true;

            using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    dr.Read();
                    Matrika.UnsecuredOut = dr.GetDecimal(0);
                    Matrika.SupportedOut = dr.GetDecimal(1);
                    Matrika.SecuredOut = dr.GetDecimal(2);
                    Matrika.UnsecuredLimit = dr.GetDecimal(3);
                    Matrika.SupportedLimit = dr.GetDecimal(4);
                    Matrika.SecuredLimit = dr.GetDecimal(5);
                    Matrika.UnsecuredTenor = dr.GetDecimal(6);
                    Matrika.SupportedTenor = dr.GetDecimal(7);
                    Matrika.SecuredTenor = dr.GetDecimal(8);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```